# Помогите разобраться с использованием sqlite на replit

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Странный и мб не по той теме вопрос, но как использовать sqlite на replit? Речь не о импорте, а именно использовании(обращение к файлу .db и написание запросов к бд на sql), который почему-то не хочет выполняться. В replit есть встроенные функции и способности бд, но хочется использовать именно sqlite